# Filter array with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I would like to filter the array below and remove any of the objects where **type** is equal to a defined variable of the same name and is false.

In the example below, the element containing type:second should be removed from the array.

```
var first = true,
  second = false,
  third = true,
  obj = {"data": [
    {"type":"first","message":"This is the first message"},
    {"type":"second","message":"This is the second message."},
    {"type":"third","message":"This is the third message."}
]};

data = obj.data;

var filtered = $.grep(data, function(v) {
    return ....
});

console.log(filtered);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ejPV4/642/

Comment: try $map() with a predicate

Comment: Why would you want to compare it to defined vars? that seems.... wrong. an object with keys would be better.

Comment: @KevinB the three variables represent three settings that can be turned on or off. If the setting is turned off, I do not want to display that message. The messages are display in a loop.

Comment: This example has been simplified too far. Is data coming from an ajax call? Why not simply define the type and modify the type during execution instead of setting separate variables? Why not use a prototype and instances for this? I think while some of these answers may hack around the current structure the original approach should be revisited.

Comment: Yes the object is from an AJAX request. The settings are in a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of variables, use an object with the types as keys.

```
var flags = {
    first: true,
    second: false,
    third: true
};
var filtered = $.grep(data, function(v) {
    return flags[v.type];
});
```

Comment: I really don't understand why this got downvoted. It's perfectly valid.

Comment: Especially since it's essentially the same as your edit to Sterling's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for that. A simple filter will work. I'm not entirely sure if you can compare a string being a variable name outside of `eval`, and I'm not even sure if I suggest this method. I suggest simply having the type to boolean and doing:

```
const validation = {
  first: true;
  second: false;
  third: true;
};
let filtered = data.filter(v => validation[v.type]);
```

You can't (you technically can, but really shouldn't) have variable variables in JavaScript. Use an object instead.

Comment: Thanks for the edit madara, that's a very good point to make here.

Comment: @madaraUchiha Completely redesigning the code is not an appropriate edit.

Comment: @Barmar he asked my approval in chat, I agreed it was a good edit.

Comment: No, but I've been in direct contact with the author before and after the edit. He may as well have written it himself.

Comment: I was thinking about variable variables but wasn't sure if that was possible in JavaScript.

Comment: It's possible with `eval`, but take that with a grain of salt. If it's something where only eval can do it, you may want to rethink your methodology.

Comment: @AsaCarter Any time you think you need variable variables, you're almost certainly doing something wrong. And `eval` should only be needed if you really want to allow the user to enter arbitrary code that should be executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var types = ['second'];
var filtered = $.grep(obj.data, function(element, index) {
  return types.indexOf(element.type) === -1;
});
```

You can set the types which you want filtered out by including them in the types array.

[Live Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMMMeY)

Comment: not sure why this is downvoted, it builds on what OP was trying to do and works

Comment: Pretty sure they were due to the original form of the answer.

Answer (score -2):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/manishtuteja10/k4jL9s8u/)

```
var obj = {"data": [
        {"type":"first","message":"This is the first message"},
        {"type":"second","message":"This is the second message."},
        {"type":"third","message":"This is the third message."}
    ]};

    var result = obj.data.filter(function(elem, index){
        return elem.type != "second";
    })

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: someone is downvoting every answer

Comment: He wants a dynamic solution where he has a set of variables that can be true or false, and all the items whose types match the true ones should be returned. Hard-coding a specific type is not an answer.

Answer (score -2):

**UPDATE**Try with this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ejPV4/646/

```
    function Stuff(){

        obj = {"data": [
              {"type":"first","message":"This is the first message"},
              {"type":"second","message":"This is the second message."},
              {"type":"third","message":"This is the third message."}
                    ]};
    Stuff.prototype.filter = function(item){
            data = obj.data;
        var remove = "";
        this.item = item;

            $.each(data,function(i,value){
              if(value.type == item){
                remove = i;
              }                 
                    });
          data.splice(remove, 1);
          return data;
     };
}

var think = new Stuff();
console.log(think.filter('first'));
```